# How Many Style XML Files Do You need with AppCompat Library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

If you are using one of the new Material Design inspired `AppCompat` themes, is there any reason to have multiple `styles.xml` files in folders such as  `values-v14` or `values-v21`?  After all, you will only need one master style, or `theme` per app.

If the answer is that multiple `styles.xml` files are still needed, where do you declare the `AppCompat` theme, in the regular `values` folder? all of them?

Comment: im wondering the same thing. if you find an answer you can answer your own question.